# get scrollbar id on windows procedure

Tags: c++, winapi, scrollbar

Here is how I create my scrollbar:

```
CreateWindowEx(NULL, L"SCROLLBAR", NULL,  WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | scrollPos, x, y, width, height, parent, (HMENU)155, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);
```

How could I restore my id (155) to know which control I will operate?

Here is how I tried:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
int wmId, wmEvent;
PAINTSTRUCT ps;
HDC hdc;
int id;
SCROLLBARINFO si;

wmId = LOWORD(wParam);
wmEvent = HIWORD(wParam);

switch (message)
{
case WM_USER:
    break;
case WM_USER + 1:
    break;
case CONNECT_TO_SERVER:
    break;
case WM_VSCROLL:
    id = GetDlgCtrlID(hWnd);
    //id isn't my 155 id, it is some kind of random number
    //wmId isn't my 155 id
    break;
case WM_COMMAND:
    break;
case WM_PAINT:
    hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    break;
case WM_DESTROY:
    PostQuitMessage(0);
    break;
default:
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
return 0;
}
```

I need to regain this id to choose which one of my controls should react inside my own grid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 id = GetDlgCtrlID(hWnd);
```

That's not correct, hWnd is the handle to your main window, not the scrollbar control.  Also beware that WM_VSCROLL can be sent both by your main window *and* the scrollbar.  The *lParam* argument tells you where it came from.  Fix:

```
case WM_VSCROLL: 
    if (lParam != 0) {
        int id = GetDlgCtrlID((HWND)lParam);
        // etc..
    } 
    break;
```

Comment: `lParam` is an `LPARAM`, but `GetDlgCtrlID()` expects an `HWND` instead, so you have to use a type-cast: `GetDlgCtrlID((HWND)lParam);` or `GetDlgCtrlID(reinterpret_cast<HWND>(lParam));`